# C# MongoDb Driver - filtering by a nullable property security check

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use .Net Core 3.1 and MongoDB Driver, and I have a method where I want to find by a property but the property is nullable. The method is the following:

```
public async Task<List<MyDataModel>> GetCustomersAsync(IEnumerable<long> ids)
    {
        var filterDefinition = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<MyDataModel>();
        var idsFilter = filterDefinition.In(x => x.Id.Value, mdmIds);

        return await this.Table.Find(idsFilter).ToListAsync();
    }
```

The thing is on x.Id.Value, if I don't perform this, it throws a compilation error Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'FieldDefinition<MyDataModel, long> because it is not a delegate type.

If I change the type of ids from long to long? it doesn't complain but am I missing something or doing something wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before that filter just add the filter which will filter out all documents that have null as an _id.
I think it's called Ne =>  filterDefinition.Ne((x => x.Id.Value, null).